# Как бороться с Segmentation fault?

Tags: php

Выполняю скрипт примерно такого содержания:

```
$text = '';
for ($i=1; $i <= 10000000; $i++) {
     $data = ....;
     $text .= $data;
}
```

В итоге после некоторого времени скрипт прерывает выполнение с сообщением: **Segmentation fault**

Я пробовал добавить в начало скрипта: `ini_set('memory_limit', '5600M');` но и это не помогает...

В чем может быть дело? php 7.1

Comment: промониторьте объем используемой памяти. оцените длину конкатенируемой строки. если у вас 32битная платформа, то макс. длина строки 2ГБ, ваш мемори лимит не поможет ничем.

Comment: @teran а как мониторить не подскажете?

Comment: вы сначала ответьте про длину строки и платформу (разрядость пхп). объем выделяемой памяти можно узнать функциями а-ля `memory_get_usage`